# Escritura de un txt con valores obtenidos

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un código que utilizo para calcular ciertos valores. Ahora, esos valores que los muestro en pantalla quiero escribirlos en un fichero. Os pongo lo que obtengo a partir del código.

Este es el código:

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

arrivals = []
with open('Dato.txt', 'rt') as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        columna = str(linea).strip().split(',')
        a = float(columna[0])
        b = float(columna[1])
        c = float(columna[2])
        d = float(columna[3])
        e = float(columna[4])
        arrival = model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
        arrivals.append(arrival)

print('Las llegadas procesadas son:', len(arrivals))
for arrival in arrivals:
    arrivals=arrival[0]
    print(arrivals.pierce)

outfile=open('Datout.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(str(arrivals.pierce))
outfile.close()
```

Cuando corro el código obtengo lo siguiente en pantalla que son las llegadas que yo necesito:

```
Las llegadas procesadas son: 2
[ ( 323.37738085,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   408.        ,  47.6981    ,  146.9212    )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.25942791e-01,   9.18383444e-05,   410.        ,  47.70292225,  146.9180712 )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.95211705e+01,   1.33680904e-02,   660.        ,  48.39912219,  146.45957792)
 ( 323.37738085,   4.30994629e+02,   3.09568047e-01,  2889.        ,  63.17117462,  131.25054174)
 ( 323.37738085,   6.19102877e+02,   7.88455257e-01,  3482.54497821,  73.50766588,   55.65029149)
 ( 323.37738085,   8.07211124e+02,   1.26734247e+00,  2889.        ,  54.05973754,    7.50927585)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.18868458e+03,   1.56354242e+00,   660.        ,  38.47340944,   -2.34102958)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23777981e+03,   1.57681868e+00,   410.        ,  37.75869395,   -2.67200616)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23820575e+03,   1.57691051e+00,   408.        ,  37.75374671,   -2.67427329)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.28179336e+03,   1.58536568e+00,   210.        ,  37.29809076,   -2.88171143)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32180477e+03,   1.59207012e+00,    35.        ,  36.93652754,   -3.04441779)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32587993e+03,   1.59253065e+00,    20.        ,  36.91168346,   -3.05553737)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.33192110e+03,   1.59307573e+00,     0.        ,  36.882277  ,   -3.068689  )]
[ ( 339.4040037,     0.        ,  0.        ,    72.        , -26.1067    , -70.511     )
 ( 339.4040037,    31.61307828,  0.00560615,   210.        , -25.88996295, -70.24724399)
 ( 339.4040037,    75.77724193,  0.01460756,   410.        , -25.54097133, -69.82576849)
 ( 339.4040037,   125.11338485,  0.02861069,   660.        , -24.99568562, -69.17495212)
 ( 339.4040037,   513.81623738,  0.34661688,  2889.        , -12.02049494, -55.64355654)
 ( 339.4040037,   686.31802725,  0.77842715,  3385.24224777,   6.41092014, -39.04674987)
 ( 339.4040037,   858.81981713,  1.21023743,  2889.        ,  24.27269118, -21.2005186 )
 ( 339.4040037,  1247.52266965,  1.52824362,   660.        ,  35.87198912,  -4.89350546)
 ( 339.4040037,  1296.85881258,  1.54224674,   410.        ,  36.33003418,  -4.07822939)
 ( 339.4040037,  1341.02297623,  1.55124816,   210.        ,  36.62152451,  -3.5491073 )
 ( 339.4040037,  1372.63605451,  1.55685431,    72.        ,  36.80187832,  -3.21754721)
 ( 339.4040037,  1381.15133229,  1.55830546,    35.        ,  36.84841279,  -3.13146868)
 ( 339.4040037,  1385.23436383,  1.55878975,    20.        ,  36.86392879,  -3.10271861)
 ( 339.4040037,  1391.28477562,  1.55936272,     0.        ,  36.882277  ,  -3.068689  )]
```

Sin embargo, en el archivo que obtengo solamente aparece la última de las dos llegadas que me sirven.

```
[ ( 339.4040037,     0.        ,  0.        ,    72.        , -26.1067    , -70.511     )
 ( 339.4040037,    31.61307828,  0.00560615,   210.        , -25.88996295, -70.24724399)
 ( 339.4040037,    75.77724193,  0.01460756,   410.        , -25.54097133, -69.82576849)
 ( 339.4040037,   125.11338485,  0.02861069,   660.        , -24.99568562, -69.17495212)
 ( 339.4040037,   513.81623738,  0.34661688,  2889.        , -12.02049494, -55.64355654)
 ( 339.4040037,   686.31802725,  0.77842715,  3385.24224777,   6.41092014, -39.04674987)
 ( 339.4040037,   858.81981713,  1.21023743,  2889.        ,  24.27269118, -21.2005186 )
 ( 339.4040037,  1247.52266965,  1.52824362,   660.        ,  35.87198912,  -4.89350546)
 ( 339.4040037,  1296.85881258,  1.54224674,   410.        ,  36.33003418,  -4.07822939)
 ( 339.4040037,  1341.02297623,  1.55124816,   210.        ,  36.62152451,  -3.5491073 )
 ( 339.4040037,  1372.63605451,  1.55685431,    72.        ,  36.80187832,  -3.21754721)
 ( 339.4040037,  1381.15133229,  1.55830546,    35.        ,  36.84841279,  -3.13146868)
 ( 339.4040037,  1385.23436383,  1.55878975,    20.        ,  36.86392879,  -3.10271861)
 ( 339.4040037,  1391.28477562,  1.55936272,     0.        ,  36.882277  ,  -3.068689  )]
```

Si os fijáis, la primera llegada sería la de la fila que empieza por el número 323 y la segunda llegada sería la de la fila que empieza por el número 339. A mí me interesa obtener un fichero que me escriba las dos llegadas (en un futuro serán bastantes más). De momento lo estoy simplificando solo con dos para hacerlo más sencillo. ¿Podríais echarme una mano para indicarme como generar ese bucle?

Disculpad mi bajo conocimiento de la programación. Muchísimas gracias.

Pongo el código final que funciona perfectamente. Gracias.

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

arrivals = []
with open('Dato.txt', 'rt') as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        columna = str(linea).strip().split(',')
        a = float(columna[0])
        b = float(columna[1])
        c = float(columna[2])
        d = float(columna[3])
        e = float(columna[4])
        arrival = model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
        arrivals.append(arrival)

print('Las llegadas procesadas son:', len(arrivals))
outfile=open('Datout.txt', 'w')
for arrival in arrivals:
    data=arrival[0]
    #print(data.pierce)
    lleg=str(data.pierce)
    outfile.write(lleg +'\n')
outfile.close()
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problemas lo tienes en estas lineas

```py
for arrival in arrivals:
    arrivals=arrival[0] #AQUI
    print(arrivals.pierce)
```

Estas asignandole a la variable `arrivals` con la ultima posición del recorrido del `for` por ende cuando escribes en el archivo esta pasandole la ultima posición.

```py
outfile.write(str(arrivals.pierce))
```

Podrias cambiar el nombre de la variable.

```py
for arrival in arrivals:
    data =arrival[0] #AQUI
    print(data.pierce)
```

Lo que se me ocurre es que mientras muestras las llegadas tambien las guardes en el archivo

```py
outfile=open('Datout.txt', 'w')

for arrival in arrivals:
    data =arrival[0]
    print(data.pierce)
    outfile.write(str(data.pierce))

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Gracias Juanmhs. He corregido lo que me indicas pero el archivo que me sigue arrojando es el que he indicado más arriba. Sigo buscando la solución o algún consejo más. Un saludo.

Comment: Te coloque otra forma de hacerlo en la solución para que veas si de esa manera te sirve

Comment: Hola. Eso ha corregido el problema y ya obtengo cada llegada incluida en el archivo .txt. Coloco el código final logrado gracias a vosotros. Muchas gracias.